# Avoid Docker to write into /var/tmp

Tags: docker, lvm, var

How can I tell docker to write data elsewhere of /var/tmp ? Like specifying another path, like /opt for example.

Because I often running out of disk usage on /var file system.

The challenge is that I don't to resize /var every time I need to load or save images from the daemon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Docker Offical Post](https://forums.docker.com/t/store-images-in-non-default-locations/77882), all you have to do is change the location in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` like this:

```
{
  "data-root": "/new/docker/data/path"
}
```

Have in mind that if you use tools that connect to a Docker environment, like VSCode, Portainer and many others, they might not be able to see/manage your images if you change the default value.